# My app runs perfectly while running it on eclipse but maps disapear and it crashes on some actvitys after export

Tags: android, export

Hw can this happen and be solved?

My app runs perfectly while on eclipse, I tried everything before exporting the app.
When I exported the app, the maps showed a grey area and the app crashed while loading one activity.

Running on eclipse none of this happens.

Is this because of the prograd configuration?

How can I debug an exported app?

Comment: Any chance of some screenshots or code? This could be one of many, many things.

Comment: Try using crash reporting tool (Try [Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com/) for example)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the Maps grey area issue do the following:

1. Open Google Developers Console
2. Select the project you are working on (or create it if it doesn't exist)
3. Select APIs & Auth
4. Then Credentials
5. Find the section with the title "**Key for Android applications**"
6. Click **Edit allowed Android applications**
7. Execute the keytool command to generate the SHA1 fingerprint for your release keystore file
8. Then add the SHA1 and package name to the list of allowed Android applications

And for the crashes, try using crash reporting tool ([Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com/) for example)